# How to solve circular imports

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models `ai_output` which defines `AIOutput` and `manual_overwrite` with `ManualOverwrite` which are both importing each other and so I get the following error:

> from main.models.manual_overwrite import ManualOverwrite
>
> ImportError: cannot import name ManualOverwrite

The only solution I could find through the django docs was solving it by removing the import of a class in one of the files, and replacing it with a string containing the name of the class

and so this:

```
aioutput = models.ForeignKey(AIOutput, null=True, blank=True)
```

became this:

```
aioutput = models.ForeignKey('ai_output.AIOutput', null=True, blank=True)
```

But now I get that:

> main.ManualOverwrite.aioutput: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation
>   with model 'ai_output.AIOutput', which is either not installed, or is
>   abstract.

Any idea how to solve the issue with circular imports? Any tip would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you forgot to add app containing `AIOutput` model to `INSTALLED_APPS`. If that is not the case, moving another app above this one in `INSTALLED_APPS` should solve the problem. On a side note, circular imports often occur when two related things are part of different apps and is probably a sign that the design might be improved such that related components stay in the same app. With that said, it is not always the case.